# Git revert for older git commit that is merged into the later commits

Tags: git, reverse, rebase

I have the following git history:

```
Development branch
    MergeCommit3
    MergeCommit2
    Commit2 (directly committed to the development branch)
    MergeCommit1
    Commit1
```

I need to create a release without the feature in `MergeCommit1`. `MergeCommit1` can stay in development, I just can't have that feature for this special release I need. So I will need to remove it only in my release branch.

The feature branches that resulted in `MergeCommit3` and `MergeCommit2` had a number of commits of their own, and also development was also merged into both couple of times, so those merges do include the `MergeCommit1`. They had some conflicts when merged in, nothing major.

Is it possible to do what I described above?
I played around with
`git revert -m 1 <MergeCommit1 hash>` but I get an error:

```
error: could not revert e22994de...

hint: after resolving the conflicts, mark the corrected paths
hint: with 'git add <paths>' or 'git rm <paths>'
hint: and commit the result with 'git commit'
```

Is this the right approach at all? Possible? Or there is another way?

Comment: One way out would be to reset to a state (before commit1) and then individually cherry-pick commits that you care about, which should go into the release branch.

Comment: Yes, priteshbaviskar is right ... but either way the chance to have conflicts is high. So some work will still have to be done by hand. Sorry :-)